# magnitude calculation if a blackbody's radius and temperature are provided

Tags: photometry, magnitude

I know it is necessary to convolve its spectrum with the transmission curve of a filter.

Are there any online tools or codes available for calculating a BB's magnitude in any specific band (e.g., UBVJHKugriz) when its surface temperature and radius are provided?

What I need is not a table. A table usually does not encompass all stellar types, let alone cover the entire range of temperatures. Besides, BB does not necessarily mean a main sequence star.

Comment: Are you looking for the colour-magnitude or hertzsprung-russel diagramme?

Comment: temperature and radius. it has nothing to with CMD or HR diagram.

Comment: colour is immediately representative of the temperature as stars are black bodies. And for main sequence stars colour, temperature, magnitude, radius and mass are not independent variables.

Comment: OK. I have changed the title.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query spectral type for absolute magnitude](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/57102/query-spectral-type-for-absolute-magnitude)

Comment: No.  arbitrary band, arbitrary temperature and radius. Not necessarily main sequence stars.  Either convolution or on-line tools or codes.